# How to Convert Oracle Spatial coordinates to Java Graphics coordinates?

Tags: java, coordinates, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation, oracle-spatial

I want to convert Oracle Spatial coordinates to java graphics coordinates.
Please help me understand how to do that conversion? 
Is there any formula available?

Comment: What units are being used for the coordinates you have stored in Oracle Spatial?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure how to convert into java graphic coordinates, but I think your first step will be to convert into JGeometry objects.  To do this have a look at "Oracle Spatial and Graph Java API" http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e20856/toc.htm

GeoRaptor is a really good open source plugin for SQL Developer.  It displays sdo_geometry data on a map windows within SQL Developer.  If looking for examples of how to display sdo_geometry data using java graphics, you could do worse than reviewing the source code:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/georaptor/